# specify libstd in cmake generated project

Tags: opencv, cmake, libstdc++

I have an OpenCV project which generates its makefiles with cmake.

If I do `cmake . && make`, it keeps report linking error. I figure this is due to the choice of `libstd`. (I have done an experiment writing a helloworld opencv project and it turns out `-libstd=libstdc++` is the key to compiling success).

How can I add the switch `-libstd=libstdc++` in a cmake prject?

In case it is helpful, my system is `OSX 10.9` and compiler `clang-503.0.40`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it with `SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-stdlib=libstdc++")`

Comment: @MattDeacalionStevens While not very expansive, this looks like a complete answer to me. Those should not be edited into the question.

Answer (score 1):

For CMake versions >= 2.8.12, you can use [`target_compile_options`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/target_compile_options.html) along with a [generator expression](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html).

Say your target is called `MyExe`, then you can do:

```
target_compile_options(MyExe PUBLIC $<$<BOOL:${APPLE}>:-stdlib=libstdc++>)
```

Comment: Thanks, but my CMake version is 2.8.10. Solved it by setting `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`